# PHP mysqli: how to detect access denied or bad parameters when connecting to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

I have the following code:

```
// Connect to DB

$mysqli = new mysqli( $host, $user, $password, $database );
if( ! $mysqli )
{
    echo "Unable to connect to database\n";
    exit(1);
}
```

If the password provided or the host name/address is invalid the mysqli object is instantiated anyway. `! $mysqli` is evaluated `false` so the connection failure is not detected.

If I check `$mysqli->error` I get no error.

What happens is that PHP (I'm using PHP 5.6 from the command line) is raising warnings. Then what fails is the first query or any other attempt to operate with the (failed) connection.

What is the best way to suppress warnings and catch the connection failure into the code?

Comment: You should be able to use mysqli::$connect_error and mysqli::$connect_errno to get details about connection errors: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

Comment: What you're going to do with this caught connection failure?

Comment: @YourCommonSense  In the case of my CLI script echo an error message and exit. If it was a web application I would redirect the client to a page with an appropriate message.

Comment: So, in effect all you want is to add a die call to the warning *you already have*?

Comment: @YourCommonSense  yes I want to stop execution right there. Doesn't this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *best* way to report mysqli errors is to set mysqli reporting mode to exceptions. In such a case all your code will be just two lines short:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli( $host, $user, $password, $database);
```

-- it will do exactly what you want: output the error message and stop the script execution.

For the web version it should remain the same, while in your web-server's config you have to setup a 500 error page, to make it shown automatically if PHP resulted in an error. E.g. for Apache,

```
ErrorDocument 500 /error.html
```

as it makes no sense to write a dedicated error handler for the every error possible.

Answer (score 0):

As [Roger Pennink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1589735/rogier-pennink) suggested `mysqli::$connect_error` and `mysqli::$connect_errno` can be inspected after the connection attempt.

As warnings can be suppressed with the `@` operator the code can be rewritten as follows:

```
// Connect to DB

@$mysqli = new mysqli( $host, $user, $password, $database );
if( ! $mysqli )
{
    echo "Unable to connect to database.\n";
    exit(1);
}
if( $mysqli->connect_errno )
{
    echo "Unable to connect to database: " . $mysqli->connect_error . "\n";
    exit(1);
}
```

Of course it should be taken in account that `@` suppresses errors too.

Answer (score -1):

We do it like this:

```
<?php
function connect($DB_HOST,$DB_NAME,$DB_USER,$DB_PWD){
    try { 
      $host=$DB_HOST;
      $dbname= $DB_NAME;
      $OPTIONEN = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
      $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $DB_USER, $DB_PWD,$OPTIONEN); 
      $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); 
      $DBH->exec("set names utf8");
      $DBH->exec("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
      return $DBH;
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) { 
        echo "Error in database-connection: {$e->getMessage()} "; 
    }
}
?>
```

Just a standard try and catch.
Or in your case:

```
try{
   $mysqli = new mysqli( $host, $user, $password, $database );
}
catch(PDOException $e) { 
   echo "Error in database-connection: {$e->getMessage()} "; 
}
```

Comment: Althought I prefer a different approach thank you for your answer. And... the downvote you got didn't come from me.